# can Julia capture the results shell command

Tags: julia

I'd like to capture the result of a shell command in julia

in ipython this works:

```
[1]: x = ! date
In [2]: x
Out[2]: ['Thu Dec 14 15:34:06 PST 2017']
```

I've already tried

```
julia> x = ;date
ERROR: syntax: unexpected ;

julia> x = readstring(`date`)
"Thu Dec 14 21:33:48 PST 2017\n"
julia> x
"Thu Dec 14 21:33:48 PST 2017\n"
```

is readstring the best way to accomplish this? or is there a ; way, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressing `;` works only in Julia REPL moving it to *>shell* mode and only if you are at the beginning of the line.

In programs `;` is expression terminator. Therefore `x = ;date` is an error because `x =` is a malformed expression.

Starting from Julia 0.7 you will not be able to use `readstring` but rather

```
read(`date`, String)
```

If you do not want a string but an array of raw bytes simply write

```
read(`date`)
```